# Print out Regular Expression Table with kable

Tags: regex, r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to create a basic reference table in RMarkdown for regular expressions, and I'm having some trouble trying to concatenate strings of characters together. I'm not really sure if I should be using the `` instead of the "" to specify these strings literally, but I'm pretty stuck. Seems like I keep getting a ton of errors around syntax. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is how the table would look in markdown code:

```
POSIX Class Name| Description             |Examples
-------------   | ------------------------|------------------------ 
[:alpha:]       |Alphanumeric characters  |[[:alpha:][:digit:]] or [A-z09]
[:punct:]       |Punctation Characters    |! \ \" # $ % & '( ) * + , - . / : ;  ? @ [ \ \ ] ^ _`{ | }~
```

However, some of these characters are hard to render in a string, (such as a null character). Below is my code for attempting to do this sample table in a dataframe.

```
#Create Charatctor class table
class_name <- c("[:alnum:]","[:alpha:]","[:ascii:]","[:blank:]","[:cntrl:]","[:digit:]","[:graph:]","[:lower:]","[:print:]",
"[:punct:]","[:space:]","[:upper:]","[:xdigit:]")
description <- c("Alphanumeric characters","Alphabetic characters","ASCII characters","Space and tab","Control characters",
"Digits","Visible characters (anything except spaces and control characters)","Lowercase letters","Visible characters and spaces (anything except control characters)","Punctuation and symbols.","All whitespace characters, including line breaks",
"Uppercase letters","Hexadecimal digits")
examples <- c(`[[:alpha:][:digit:]] or [A-z0-9]`,
              `[[:lower:][:upper:]] or [A-z]`,
              `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`,
              `[ \t]`,
              "\nor\r,[\x\0\0-\x1F\x7F]",
              `or \d: digits, 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, equivalent to [0-9]`,
              `[:alnum:] and [:punct:]`,
              `[a-z]`,
              `[[:alnum:][:punct:]\\s]`,
              `! \ \" # $ % & '( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ \ ] ^ _`{ | }~` )

char_class <- data.frame(class_name,description,examples)
names(char_class) <- c("Class Name","Description","Examples")

#View the Table
kable(char_class, col.names = names(char_class), align = c('c','l'), caption = "Character Class Examples")
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
Error: '\x' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\nor\r,[\x"
Error: nul character not allowed (line 5)
```

Part of what I'm trying to do is to put together a reference guide for Regular Expressions in R, but it's pretty hard to print out these characters other than with normal markdown, but I'd like to get the data in a data frame if possible to use kable's formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't test your entire script at the moment, but try replacing `\nor` with `\\nor`.  This escaping problem is probably causing errors in a few other places.

Comment: That's not legal R code. Try it in an ordinary R console session. Many of the single backslashes are throwing errors. See `?Syntax`. The `\nor` is legal but the `\x` is not. `\n` is a carriage return. You should say what you expect to see.

Comment: I know it's throwing errors, that's why I posted the question. I want to have the literal string, but I just get a ton of errors. Are you really not able to store these characters in vectors, such as this nul character not allowed (line 1).
?

Comment: Again: You should say what you intend to do with these structures. Are you planning on using `cat()` to display? If you want the two character string of backslash followed by an ordinary "x" ... then it is "\\x"

Comment: I want to create a dataframe with these vectors of regular expressions so you can see an clear example characters for each POSIX character class. Currently, the only way to do it is with pure markdown, as it allows you to type out certain variables that just can't be printed out. I'd like to put this in a table, but I don't think R can escape certain items, like a null chracater.

Comment: Most of these are NOT regular expressions although they are admittedly about regular expressions. Can you narrow this down to a simple example rather than trying to have us fix all of your misunderstandings of R's syntax? Furthermore, one I fix what I _think are errors in the definition of `examples` I find there are only 10 of them and 13 of `class_name`

Comment: I'm not trying to print out a regular expression. I want to print out the characters associated with each character class for regular expressions in R, and store them in a string so that I can then use to populate a row in my table. Does that make sense?

Comment: When I started making comments ... it did seem to makes sense but I'm starting to wonder now. I don't do chat. I suggested: make a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing all the single backslashes (with doubled backslashes) before items that were not listed R specials like "\n" and "\t" as described in `?Syntax` and `?Quotes` and omitting the last three of the class_name and description vectors (since they had no corresponding items the examples vector, it is possible to make a legal R dataframe:

```
class_name <- c("[:alnum:]","[:alpha:]","[:ascii:]","[:blank:]","[:cntrl:]","[:digit:]","[:graph:]","[:lower:]","[:print:]",
"[:punct:]","[:space:]","[:upper:]","[:xdigit:]")
description <- c("Alphanumeric characters","Alphabetic characters","ASCII characters","Space and tab","Control characters",
"Digits","Visible characters (anything except spaces and control characters)","Lowercase letters","Visible characters and spaces (anything except control characters)","Punctuation and symbols.","All whitespace characters, including line breaks",
"Uppercase letters","Hexadecimal digits")
examples <- c('[[:alpha:][:digit:]] or [A-z0-9]',
              '[[:lower:][:upper:]] or [A-z]',
              'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
              '[ \t]',
              "\\nor\\r,[\\x\\0\\0-\\x1F\\x7F]",
              'or \\d: digits, 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, equivalent to [0-9]',
              '[:alnum:] and [:punct:]',
              '[a-z]',
              '[[:alnum:][:punct:]\\s]',
              '! \\ \\" # $ % & \\\' ( ) * + \\, - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _ { | } ~ ' )

char_class <- data.frame(class_name[1:10],description[1:10],examples)
names(char_class) <- c("Class Name","Description","Examples")
```

#

```
> char_class
   Class Name                                                        Description
1   [:alnum:]                                            Alphanumeric characters
2   [:alpha:]                                              Alphabetic characters
3   [:ascii:]                                                   ASCII characters
4   [:blank:]                                                      Space and tab
5   [:cntrl:]                                                 Control characters
6   [:digit:]                                                             Digits
7   [:graph:] Visible characters (anything except spaces and control characters)
8   [:lower:]                                                  Lowercase letters
9   [:print:] Visible characters and spaces (anything except control characters)
10  [:punct:]                                           Punctuation and symbols.
                                                                Examples
1                                       [[:alpha:][:digit:]] or [A-z0-9]
2                                          [[:lower:][:upper:]] or [A-z]
3                   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
4                                                                  [ \t]
5                                        \\nor\\r,[\\x\\0\\0-\\x1F\\x7F]
6               or \\d: digits, 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, equivalent to [0-9]
7                                                [:alnum:] and [:punct:]
8                                                                  [a-z]
9                                                [[:alnum:][:punct:]\\s]
10 ! \\ \\" # $ % & \\' ( ) * + \\, - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _ { | } ~
```

The R `print` function (which is what is displaying these above) shows backslashes as "\". A character value of "\" contains a single character, namely a backslash. If you display it with `cat` you will see only that character, but there is no `cat`-method for items of class-`"data.frame"`:

```
> print("\\")
[1] "\\"
> cat("\\")
\
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I knew you had to escape the characters, but I wasen't sure how to string it all together into one cohesive line. \n is used to detect a newline character in regular expressions, but I don't know you can use it in R like \\n

Comment: That's true ... except inside regex character-class square-brackets where all characters except "^", ":" and "]" are literals. See `?regex` to see whether I am remembering this all correctly. (I might not be.)